# iOS : How to add run script properly?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to getting error logs from [Parse Crash reporting](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#crashreporting/iOS) for my app, its logging but not showing symbolic crash reports, also at Parse they're asking to add symbolic files for my app. I'd search for it and found that needs to upload symbolic files each time when you create a new build.

This is the sample script from Parse:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd "<path_to_cloudcode_folder>"
parse symbols -p "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

I want to add dynamic path to `path_to_cloudcode_folder` because we're working remotely via git so the `path_to_cloudcode_folder` is different based on each user.

How do I add a dynamic path there, so it will work at all of the places without error.

P.S. I thought $SCRROOT would work, but it won't. It gives me error,

> No such file or directory.

What's wrong?

```
echo $SCRROOT
```

gives me following folder path,

> /Hagile/Workspace/Git/TestApp

Above path contains a folder, parse having 3 sub folders. i.e.

```
- Hagile |

 - Workspace |

  - Git |

   - TestApp |

     - cloud | config | public
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Julian answer help me to get this working ! I needed to change it little.

```
echo "-start-----------------------------"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd "${PROJECT_DIR}"/parse
parse symbols -p "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
echo "-end-----------------------------"
```

Here's the output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

`cd "${PROJECT_DIR}"/<path to cloud folder>/parse`

My problem laid in the fact that I had spaces in my path and this was tripping up the compiler. Providing the double quotes did it for me.

See this more [in-depth explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108635/why-i-cant-escape-spaces-on-a-bash-script).

Comment: Please read my question again, this doesn't answer to my question. I don't have to write any command in terminal. I've to add script to send symbolic constant to parse.

Comment: I think I understood your question correctly. The script line I provided is the second line of that very same sample script in my specific scenario.